# Queues and iteration issue

Tags: java, loops, queue, iteration

Could anyone help me with this question? I don't get how to solve it or even how to start.

The following code segment is a count controlled loop going from 1 through 5. At each iteration, the loop counter is either printed or put on a queue depending on the boolean result returned by the method random(assume that random randomly returns either true or false).

At the end of the loop, the elements in the queue are removed and printed. Because of the logical properties of a queue this code segment cannot print certain sequences of the values of the loop counter. You are given an output and asked to determine whether the code segment could generate the output.

```
for(count = 1; count <= 5; count++) {
   if(random())
      system.out.println(count);
   else 
      queue.enqueue(count);  
}
while (!queue.isEmpty())
{
   number = queue.dequeue();
   system.out.println(number);
}
```

1. the following out is possible: 1 2 3 4 5
   true, false or not enough information?
2. the following out is possible: 1 3 5 4 2
   true, false or not enough information?
3. the following out is possible: 1 3 5 2 4
   true, false or not enough information?

Comment: It's the second homework question you post today, without showing any kind of effort. What do you think the answer is? What's your reasoning about it?

Comment: When is it wrong to ask for understanding? You just chose to judge it as u wished? Check my questions, each one of them is asking for understanding not for the answer directly.

Comment: Read the tooltip that appears when your mouse is on the "Downvote" link (down arrow). It says "The question doesn't show any research effort". I think your question matches with that. You've not shown any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a.** *true*. This is the case where `random()` returned *true* 5 times (This will happen in a probability of 0.03125)

**b.** Lets assume it's *true*:

**Possible scenario:**

When `i = 1` `random()` returned *true* so it printed 1.

Then, in order for **b** to be true as we assumed, in `i = 2` it must be that `random()` returned *false* (otherwise the program will print 1 in contradiction of our assumption).

So, we're going to the else statement and enqueue 1.

The same for `i = 3`.

Now we want 4 to be printed, lets assume `random()` returned *true*.

So, in the queue we have:  2  3  5

.. Continue thinking about it this way and you'll know the answer.

The key for solving this is to assume:

**Whenever you want, you can assume that `random()` is true/false.**

Comment: Maroun, i understood a from the start, the case where random is all true, but for b and c i didnt get well, b is true ? Since it prints 1,3,5 if all were true and and 4 2 dequed? Or am i on the wrong track?

Comment: b is true. This will happen if you `random()` is: **true, false, true, false false**.

Comment: maroon, wouldnt it also be true, false, true, false, true?

Comment: Then it'll print 1 3 5 4 2

Comment: oh ok, so for i=5 it could be true or false in case b.

Comment: About C, i just tried solving it. I got false? am i right?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't get how to solve it or even how to start.

Here is a suggestion on how to start:

Using pen and paper, simulate several runs of the program (randomly choosing one of the two branches instead of each `random()` call), and see if you spot any regularities. Even if you don't, there are only 32 different paths through the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing. Looking at the console, I will print out count if random() is true. Otherwise I will enqueue it. Then I'm going to print out the queue at the end, making every number 1-5 inclusive print out without knowing the actual order. It would be more useful to have the println in the queue look like this:
    System.out.println("Queue " + number);

Comment: thanks, ill just use paper and pen for all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop goes from 1 to 5. However, any number of these could be put into a queue and printed at the end.

There are therefore three clear scenarios:

1. All entries were printed (none are queued). You will get 12345.
2. All entries are queued. Again you will get 12345.
3. Some entries were printed - some entries were queued.

In case 3, clearly you will get **two increasing sequences** where **numbers missing from the first sequence appear in the second sequence**.

So, now you can see what to expect, I would suggest you start thinking about how you would recognise these.